# Hard disk not properly working

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

I have a 4tb Seagate expansion hard disk which worked fine I used it for quiet a while and had 2 partitions , only one partition was bit locked
Yesterday I removed bit lock protection and in the middle of the process the computer shut down because the main switch was turned off by someone for some reason and I didn't have a ups so

Now when I connect my hard disk it doesn't show up in file explorer and in disk management shows a hard disk is connected and shows the 2 partitions but only the sizes shows no names nothing

What can I do

Comment: Get the Seagate Hard Drive test app and test the drive. You will likely find that the drive has errors.

Comment: The software won't work it just freezes on "searching for supported devices".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suggested to get and run the Seagate Hard Drive test app and test
> the drive.
>
> You responded that The software won't work it just freezes on
> "searching for supported devices

So the hard drive has failed and it needs to be replaced.

It appears the data will not be readily recoverable and you will need a local agency to try to recover the data.